# Is it legitimate to store a JSON object as the value attribute of a checkbox input?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a HTML table from which the user will check the row if they want to perform a particular action on that row.

Rather than creating logic which picks out the key data from the row I wish to store the key values in the value attribute of the input checkbox.

My question is, is this legitimate:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{'id': 100, 'postcode': 'WA8 6QF'}" />
```

This way I can use jQuery selectors to pick out the checked boxes and loop through them, performing the action using the items in the value JSON object.

Comment: It might work but you still shouldn't do it. You are not using the attribute as it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use HTML5 [`data-*`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-value='{"id": 100, "postcode": "WA8 6QF"}' />

var val = $('input:checkbox').data('value')
```

Comment: Upvote for letting me know that these data- attributes exist. Those are so useful, thank you.

Comment: My favorite thing about these attributes is that when you pull out json, it is automatically deserialized into a js object. sweet B)

Comment: U just saved me, i was a second away of using refs in react

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that, you may use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) of `jQuery`:

```
$(':checkbox').data({'id': 100, 'postcode': 'WA8 6QF'});
```

*markup* equivalent is this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="100" data-postcode="'WA8 6QF'" />
```

and then retrieve like this:

```
$(':checkbox').data('id')   //100
$(':checkbox').data('postcode') //'WA8 6QF'
```

Answer (score 1):

the `value` of an `input:checkbox` element can be any string, so a JSON object is perfectly valid. You will have to be sure to make sure that it's a properly encoded JSON object ([`"` for quoting strings, not `'`](http://www.json.org/)) and that it's also correctly HTML-escaped.

The example you provided is invalid JSON:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{'id': 100, 'postcode': 'WA8 6QF'}" />
```

Instead, you should have:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{&quot;id&quot;:100,&quot;postcode&quot;:&quot;WA8 6QF&quot;}" />
```

It's due to these sorts of encoding issues that most people would discourage this sort of usage. There's nothing wrong with it per-se, but it's very easy to make mistakes that go unnoticed.

That all being said, if you simply want to associate data with an element, jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method is much easier to use, and you wont have to worry about encoding.

Additionally, if you're passing information from the server. jQuery's `data` method will pull out the information from all the `[data-*]` attributes:

```
<input id="example" type="checkbox" data-id="100" data-postcode="WA8 6QF" value="...some value..." />
<script>//ideally in an external .js file rather than inline
    var exampleData = $('#example').data();
</script>
```

`exampleData` will be:

```
{
    id: 100, //will even be nicely cast to a Number
    postcode: 'WA8 6QF'
}
```

Comment: @Jashwant, JSON objects must use `"` characters, otherwise it's invalid JSON.

Comment: Yes, but he can do `<input type="checkbox" value='{"id": 100, "postcode": "WA8 6QF"}' />`

Comment: @Jashwant, i'm just trying to be thorough, anyone who understands the nuances of when you can use different encodings should take shortcuts as they see fit. `value='{"Conan":"O'Brien"}'` would be an easy error to miss.

Comment: very much true. I was just clarifying my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan to POST this to the server?

if by normal _POST submission, you could probably just have paired input hidden tags

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" />
<input type="hidden" name="d1" value="{'id': 100, 'postcode': 'WA8 6QF'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

*Is it legitimate to store a JSON object as the value attribute of a checkbox input ?*

`"{'id': 100, 'postcode': 'WA8 6QF'}"` is a string after all.

So, **its legitimate to store this string**

But, since its not a valid json, you may not be able to use it later.

So fix this, you should do,

```
<input type="checkbox" value='{"id": 100, "postcode": "WA8 6QF"}' />
```

*(the keys should have double quotes around them)*

**So, you can, but you shouldnt. Use `data` attributes as explained by others.**